# How to loop 2 dates to output like this?

Tags: php, date

Here's my code that display date with for loop.

Topic: Im creating a script to generate payment due(from to start).

```
     $y = 1;
        $period = 3;
        $start = date('m/15/Y');
echo "<table>";
echo '<thead><th>From</th>';
echo '<th>To</th></thead>';
        for ($y; $y <= $period; $y++) {
            $month_mid = date("m/15/Y", strtotime($start));
            $month_last = date("m/t/Y", strtotime($start));
                echo '<td>'.$month_mid = date("m/t/Y", strtotime($start)).'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$month_last = date("m/15/Y", strtotime($start)).'</td></tr>';
           $start = date("m/d/Y",strtotime($start." +1month"));
        }
echo '</table>';
```

output I get:

```
 09/15/2017 09/30/2017
 10/15/2017 10/31/2017
 11/15/2017 11/31/2017
```

I want to appear like this:

```
09/15/2017 09/30/2017
09/30/2017 10/15/2017
10/15/2017 10/31/2017
```

Im new in date php hope you can help me with this thanks.

Comment: Ok, do you need help in formatting the date or positionating it in the output?

Comment: @Lioo positioning by output sir. to display it in table.

Comment: It's unclear what you want, what you've done, and what the problem is.  Remember that no one here is going to write your code for you. This feels a bit like homework, as well, so you should be clear if this is the case.

Comment: @jdv Im pointing in how you will position the date range.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest working this out on paper. It looks like a pretty straightforward algorithm. Get two dates, start and end. Display. Start loop, using the last end as the new start. Repeat until done.

Comment: @jdv thanks for advice. but have you seen the difference on my output and what I want to appear?

Comment: It is unclear what you actually want, actually. I don't care what the dates are; *you do*. And if the whitespace is significant, that's just silly. This is a pseudo-bi-weekly date algorithm. The details, which you never shared with us, are your concern. This is why I advised writing down, in English, what you want to do. It will clarify it for you and for us.

Comment: @jdv unclear? lol you better start reading it again. see the difference output and expected output.

Comment: I've read enough to know you need to start writing some code.

Comment: @jdv check the difference between output and expected output. its different! lol

Comment: @jdv Agreed. We need more detail in **what you want to do**, not **what result you expect to output**. The logic that you want, not the final result;

Comment: its like a payment. from and to due date.

Comment: You could also calculate your date ranges ahead of time, store them in a collection, and then output them as necessary. It depends on how many there are per run. But that would be a time-space trade-off that might be easier because it separates the data from the presentation. (Something PHP code often needs help with.)

Comment: So, start at the beginning: do you need to know _how_ to get your date ranges? What are the edge conditions? What are the limits? Specific problems along those lines will get your best answers.

Comment: @jdv payment always at 15 or end of the month.

Comment: Ok, so this is a "semi-monthly" date calculation, with the additional requirement that the output be formatted in a specific manner using those dates. These are the details that should be _in the question_, along with any other relevant details and the _specific problem you are having._ Is it just the output formatting you are having a problem with?

Comment: @jdv I dont have problem with the computation. The only problem Im gettin' is that I need to get the output as I expected. but still getting way far output.

Comment: It's your start date that you save at the end of the loop. You are bumping it one month and then using that as a basis for the month_mid calculation. But there are a fair amount of red flags in this code, including the fact that you're using formatted date strings to get epoch dates back into strings. I'd recommend getting your two dates as epoch dates and then outputting them in whatever format you need. Then you just need to save the previous last date as the start. Separate data from display a bit and it will be easier to figure out.

Comment: PHP has a lot of handy datetime stuff now that might make your job easier. Might want to check http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
 $y = 1;
    $period = 5;
    $start = date('m/15/Y');
    echo "<table>";
    echo '<thead><th>From</th>';
    echo '<th>To</th></thead>';

    for ($y; $y <= $period; $y++) {
        $month_mid = date("m/15/Y", strtotime($start));
        $month_last = date("m/t/Y", strtotime($start));
            echo '<tr><td>'.$month_mid = date("m/t/Y", strtotime($start)).'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$month_last = date("m/15/Y", strtotime($start)).'</td></tr>';
       $start = date("m/d/Y",strtotime($start." +1month"));
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

You missed the opening and clousure of `table` and `<tr>`.

Comment: Hi I dont have problem with the table or tr. I was pointing on how to get the result what I have posted. Please check thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to be skipping ahead by a month in your loop. Well, not the way you are doing it here.

You should use `DatePeriod::getEndDate` and `DatePeriod::getStartDate`, along with `DateTime::add` to skip by semi-monthly amounts. The idea is that you only get to the next month by letting the datetime API add 15 days to a given start date, and use that to figure out the mid-month and end-month dates.

Keep everything in these date objects until you need to format and print them, and save the second one in the pair as input for the next round of the loop at the end where you just have to calculate the new second value.

I feel like you could write a function that gets the "next" date from any other first or last date of the month to simplify the loop.

(Since this is semi-monthly and not bi-weekly, you can actually just walk the months in your period, hard-coding the 15th for one value and using your end-of-month function for the second. It depends on your requirements and how complicated the API gets.)

**Or**

For each month in your period, calculated the mid-month (i.e., exactly 15 days from the start of the month) and end-month dates. Save them in a Collection of couplets of some sort.

Write a display routine that takes this Collection and outputs the dates, but saves the previous formatted string made from the second item in the couplet as the first item to be printed (after the first line.)

I actually prefer this one because it separates the presentation from the data abstraction, allowing you freedom to display and format the date how you see fit.

But, at the end of the day (pun not intended, but what a great pun), stop using date strings as input to figure out other dates when you have access to normalized epoch representations. This will only lead to madness.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $y = 1;
        $period = 3;
        $start = date('m/d/Y');
        $end = date('m/t/Y');
        echo "<table>";
        echo '<thead><th>From</th>';
        echo '<th>To</th></thead>';

        for ($y; $y <= $period; $y++) {
         echo '<tr><td>'.$start.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$end.'</td></tr>';

         $getLast = date('d',strtotime($end));

             if($getLast >= 28) {
                $start = date("m/t/Y", strtotime($start)); 
                $end = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("+15 day", strtotime($end))); 
             }else {
                $start = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("+15 day", strtotime($start))); 
                $end = date("m/t/Y",strtotime($end));   
             }
        }

        echo "</table>";
```

Result:

```
From    To
09/15/2017  09/30/2017
09/30/2017  10/15/2017
10/15/2017  10/31/2017
```